# Only create BCP error file if an error occurs

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Using `bcp`, I am importing a file into SQL Server.  I am using the error file parameter `-e errorfilename.txt`, but this file is created for every `bcp` run even when there is not an error.  Is there a way to only write an error file if there is an actual error?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is how the `-e` option works; [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#e) says:

> **-e** err_file Specifies the full path of an error file used to store any rows that the bcp utility cannot transfer from the file to the
>   database. Error messages from the bcp command go to the workstation of
>   the user. **If this option is not used, an error file is not created**.

So it seems that the only way to prevent errorfile creation is to avoid using `-e` option, but this is not what you want.

As a workaround you can use Powershell to run bcp and delete all empty files after the bcp command completes. For example:

```
$yourPath="F:\bcp_error"
bcp YOUR_DB.YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE in F:\BCP\data_file_1.bcp -c -T -e $yourPath\errorfilename_1.txt
bcp YOUR_DB.YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE in F:\BCP\data_file_2.bcp -c -T -e $yourPath\errorfilename_2.txt
bcp YOUR_DB.YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE in F:\BCP\data_file_n.bcp -c -T -e $yourPath\errorfilename_n.txt
Get-ChildItem -Path $yourPath | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item
```